# I was terminated after my last new job interview

Tags: hiring-process, new-job, termination

I was terminated during extended probation, due to a mismatch between my seniority and my competence, according to my boss.

This was my 6th month, and although my colleagues don't agree with her and everybody acknowledges my skills, she terminated me saying I was not competent enough. I always felt she had a grudge on me since my first month.

Indeed, my last day was on June 20th, and I new employer made their offer on June 22nd.

My last job interview was on June 12th, where I was threatened to be terminated at the end of the month, but I didn't mention any of it, to my back then potential future employer.

The thing is that to my knowledge it's very uncommon to be terminated if one had to resign from a previous job, unless there was a severe mistake made by the employee.

Would my new employer be worried if they discover (through paper work) I was terminated instead of naturally resigning?

Comment: Risky compared to what?  To not getting an offer from a new employer and being employed?  And it depends on why you were terminated.  If the previous employer fired you for embezzling, for example, that would very likely impact the new employer's thinking.  If the previous employer laid you off because there was less work coming in, that would be much less likely to affect the new employer.

Comment: Hello, and welcome.  You have asked three really broad questions in one question.  Maybe you can make this more specific??

Comment: I included one answer with the hopes of helping you @user , however more context and detail could serve your post well, so we can get a better idea an provide better answers. Please edit your post, otherwise it will be closed

Comment: @Neo yes, I can edit afterwards, or just delete my post if it's of no longer use

Comment: Are you saying you got a job offer and at the same time you were fired for an unrelated reason?

Comment: @user I see you edited your post, but we need a bit more details. Did this firing burn any bridges? How was your performance on that job?

Comment: My boss was not clear, but she had a grudge since my first month, and terminated me on my sixth month, and she tried to explain that I was not competent enough. But my colleagues don't agree with her and everybody acknowledges my skills.

Comment: I edited the post and included this context you are telling us, and also trimmed down some of the question to keep this focused. Feel free to add any more details that could help

Comment: @Dukeling That's the exact question I had. The OP is making it sound like he/she is in the middle of a interview and then got fired. But in other parts, it sounds like a generalized question.

Comment: @Dukeling, my last day was on Wednesday, and I received an offer to be hired on Friday. Is it a final decision or if I provide a document stating I was terminated, I would be in trouble?

Comment: @user I see you haven't provided all the context to us... are you without jobs at the moment, or already got and accepted an offer... please add ALL relevant details; continuously changing your post is confusing and hard to help

Comment: Question edited.

Comment: Are all your dates supposed to be the same month?  Your question is confusing.  How can you get benefits 2 days after your last day and 8 days after you were interviewed?

Comment: Were you really terminated or did the company choose to not continue your employment after or during a probation period?

Comment: My boss chose not to continue my employment during probation.

Comment: I called my potential new employer and they said my document is ready but they are waiting somebody's signature. Does this sound familiar or was it a mere euphemism technique?

Answer (score 6):

> Is it risky to get an offer for new employer just after being
>   terminated by current employer?

You mentioned you were terminated because of "*a mismatch between my seniority and my competence*" so I guess the question you need to ask yourself is are you selling yourself to be someone you are not? Only you can answer that question as you know your own ability. If you are not, then no, this should not be risky. It is fairly beneficial for your circumstances.

> What are the chances that this new job would be impacted by such an
>   event?

As you have already received an offer, I would be comfortable making an assumption that the company in question has already received any enquiries necessary regarding previous employment. **If they don't ask, there is no reason to tell them.** On the other hand, if they do ask, **always** tell the truth. You don't want to get into employment based on lies, it will never end well.

If the new company does find out, the result of which is not something we can answer here. Different companies will take this sort of news differently.

> Could my new employer change their mind if they think I need to resign
>   while I am free? Should I tell them I am free? No two weeks notice
>   needed?

What have you told them already about your situation? You don't need to tell them unnecessary details about your previous employment if it wont affect you. I personally would stick to whatever I told them in the past, if you told them you need to give two weeks notice, give them a reasonable date and they won't question it. If you have not told them previously to this offer (which I find unlikely) then when they eventually ask, just tell the truth that you do not have to wait any notice period.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it risky to get an offer for new employer just after being terminated by current employer?

**Depends on the nature of your termination.**

If you were fired, perhaps because something not so positive you did or some problem, then that would probably affect your chances.

On the other hand, if you ended your last job smoothly then there is nothing to worry about.

> What are the chances that this new job would be impacted by such an event?
>   Could my new employer change their mind?

Most of the times it is better/recommended to job-hunt while still employed, so a sudden firing could leave you in a less advantageous position.

Again, this depends in part of the nature of your termination, and also the way you portray it during interviews or similar. However, I think that **a termination would ring some alerts to most of the recruiters I know**.

---

**Edit post clarification:**

It seems that your firing was not because some offense or something to worry about, so I doubt that this will be a stain on your record. Also, you were there for 6 months, which is perhaps the minimum decent time worth including on your resume, so surely no job-hopper.

The tricky part will be how you explain this to possible recruiters (if they asked), as still a sudden termination could make some of them wonder. The good thing is that **you seem to have colleagues back there that could reference your work**, and if you actually did some interesting contributions in your past job you will be able to back up your claims and clear any doubts the recruiter may have.

Comment: Aren't all firing "sudden?" I never heard of someone being told they were about to get fired especially a non-management position. Sometimes you know you might get fired with a little hint and given some time to secure a new job before it happens.

Comment: @Dan I edited my post to reflect the context clarified by OP, and also changed the sudden wording to avoid semantic problems

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad question.

It depends on why you were terminated.  Was it was a position elimination because of changing business conditions (work in this field long enough and that will happen to you) or where you terminated *for cause* (such as stealing from the company?

Only you can answer this.

Just a question - were you terminated because you were looking for another job?  I work with someone that had this happen to them - one of the interviewers at the new company had a buddy at the old company.  Word got back to the old company and he was fired out if spite.

**EDIT:**  The original poster responded that is was a position mismatch between skills and seniority.  In this case it would be my belief that the shouldn't affect the new position.  Unless the he runs into the same issue with the new job.  That is a different question.